# Duplicate id in list: 003E000001YDH1jIAH on update lstContacts

Tags: apex

```
 if( !contacts.values().isEmpty() ){
              list<Contact> lstContacts = new list<Contact>();
              for( list<Contact> lstCon : contacts.values() ){
                lstContacts.addAll( lstCon );
              }
              if( !lstContacts.isEmpty() )
                update lstContacts;
            }
```

Comment: Try this  _italic_ **bold** `if( !contacts.values().isEmpty() ){
 Map<Id, Contact> lstContacts = new Map<Id, Contact>();
 for(Contact lc : contacts.values() ){
  if(!lstContacts.contsinsKey(lc.Id)){
   lstContacts.add( lc );
  }
 }
 if( !lstContacts.values().isEmpty() )
 update lstContacts.values();
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming `contacts` is map of contact Id to contact

So you do this way

1. You can just directly perform update on

   `Update contacts.values();`
2. Another way

So you can use a `Map` to check the contact Id is contains or not then add into list for update.

```
if( !contacts.values().isEmpty() ){
      map<Id, contact> mapContacts = new map<Id,contact>(contacts.values());
     update mapContacts.values();
}
```