# Can I use set<Sobject> instead of List<Sobject> to resolve the duplicate id issue

Tags: apex, set

If you take a look into this issue

[Duplicate id in list: 003E000001YDH1jIAH](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114242/duplicate-id-in-list-003e000001ydh1jiah-on-update-lstcontacts)

I have provide an answer of using `set<Sobject>` instead using `list<Sobject>`

i.e.

```
if( !contacts.values().isEmpty() ){
  set<Contact> setContacts = new set<Contact>();
  for( Contact objCon : contacts.values() ){
    if(!setContacts.contains(objCon)){
        setContacts.add( objCon );
    }
  }
 update new list<Contact>(setContacts);
}
```

even `if(!setContacts.contains(objCon))` is not needed

```
if( !contacts.values().isEmpty() ){
  set<Contact> setContacts = new set<Contact>();
  for( Contact objCon : contacts.values() ){
        setContacts.add( objCon );
  }
 update new list<Contact>(setContacts);
}
```

So is there any condition/use case where this answer might fail?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. Any field variation will cause the records to hash differently, even if they have the same Id. This is why `Map<Id, SObject>` is preferable.

```
Id commonId = '001000000000000AAA';
Account a = new Account(Id=commonId, Name='A');
Account b = new Account(Id=commonId, Name='B');
Set<Account> records = new Set<Account> { a, b };

system.assertEquals(2, records.size());

system.assertNotEquals(system.hashCode(a), system.hashCode(b));
```

Comment: Yeah Agree nice use case.. I think I need to update my Ans.. Thank for your help. :-)

Comment: Perfect time to vote for https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aDnYAAU so we can at least built our own HashSet<T> implementation.